# Combine two Maps with same key type, but different value type in scala

Tags: scala, mapping

I want to combine two Maps with the same type of key, but different type of value.

The result should have values containing with both value types (optional, because some values could be present in only one of the input Maps)

The type anotation is

```scala
def combineMaps[T, U, V](map1: Map[T, U], map2: Map[T, V]): Map[T, (Option[U], Option[V])] = {
  ???
}
```

I know it could be achieved with complicated code like:

```scala
(map1.mapValues(Some(_) -> None).toList ++ map2.mapValues(None -> Some(_)).toList) // List[(T, (Option[U], Option[V]))]
      .groupBy(_._1)                                                               // Map[T, List[(T, (Option[U], Option[V]))]]
      .mapValues(_.map(_._2))                                                      // Map[T, List[(Option[U], Option[V])]]
      .mapValues { list => (
        list.collectFirst { case (Some(u), _) => u },
        list.collectFirst { case (_, Some(v)) => v }
      ) }                                                                          // Map[T, (Option[U], Option[V])]
```

Although the code is working, it does not benefit from the fact that every key in a Map is present only once. Method `.toList` drop this type information.

I am looking for some elegant scala way to do it (possibly with cats/scalaz, but best without them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah **cats** has you covered, this is what the [`Align` typeclass](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Align.html) provides.

You only need to do:

```scala
m1.align(m2)
```

That will return a `Map[T, Ior[U, V]]` which is better than a pair of `Options` since `Ior` preserves the fact that at least one of the two elements must exists.

Answer (score 1):

A union of the `keySet`s followed by mapping the keys to tuples of `get`s should do it:

```
def combineMaps[T, U, V](m1: Map[T, U], m2: Map[T, V]): Map[T, (Option[U], Option[V])] =
  (m1.keySet union m2.keySet).map(k => (k, (m1.get(k), m2.get(k)))).toMap
```

Example:

```
combineMaps(Map('a'->1, 'b'->2, 'c'->3), Map('a'->10.0, 'c'->30.0, 'd'->40.0))
// res1: Map[Char,(Option[Int], Option[Double])] = Map(
//   a -> (Some(1),Some(10.0)), b -> (Some(2),None), c -> (Some(3),Some(30.0)), d -> (None,Some(40.0))
// )
```